# Unable to enable developer mode on Pixelbook blocked for GSuite managed device

Tags: google-chrome-os, chromebook, google-workspace

I have aGSuite enrolled Chromebook (Google Pixelbook) that I no longer want to use with GSuite. Want to now enable Developer Mode and use as a personal device.

So I deprovisioned the device in GSuite Admin to remove the enterprise management and intended to reinstall ChromeOS from a recovery USB flash drive. That worked - the device shows as deprovisioned and I was able to reinstall ChromeOS from the USB flash drive.

However, when I try to enable developer mode (hold down ESC-Refresh while booting, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>) I’m told “The device owner has disabled Developer Mode for this device.”

Searching around, I found the setting I wanted to change is “Skip Boot Mode Check for Verified Access” in GSuite Admin (Device Management > Chrome > Device Settings). When I do that, it still doesn’t allow developer mode on the device.

I would have thought the reinstall of ChromeOS would clear this but the setting apparently persists, even on a deprovisioned device.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

The key is **deprovisioning** the device stopped pushing policies to the device - so when I made the change to “Skip Boot Mode Check for Verified Access” (which should have allowed me to enable developer mode), the device didn't get that policy change since it was deprovisioned.

Sure enough, drilling into the device information for the deprovisioned device shows the last time it synced policies was yesterday - before I made the change to allow developer mode.

The trick is to reenroll the device in the enterprise, which will then push down the policy changes, and *then* enable developer mode. Of course, the device is now a managed device, so I will also need to do the ChromeOS recovery again (powerwash on an GSuite managed device just removes user data).